# How do I avoid this stale closure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on building a simple React slider which will expose internal methods up to its parent via a ref and I am having trouble with what I suspect to be a stale closure, but I can't fully understand what is actually happening. Hoping someone can help me understand here.

Here is a simplified version of the code that I ***want*** to work:

```js
const Slider = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const sliderRef = useRef();
  const [slides, dispatchSlides] = useReducer(reducer, []);

  sliderRef.current = {
    countSlides: () => {
      return slides.length
    },
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => sliderRef.current);

  return null;
```

After this component mounts, its children will render and fill up the `slides` reducer with information on their positioning and visibility using `IntersectionObserver`. This part works, so I have kept it out of this example for simplicity. For our sake, just assume that `slides` is immediately populated with objects after mount, and that a user will manually call `countObjects` from the parent component much later after `slides` has been populated.

In the parent component, if I execute `countSlides` from the ref, I will always see `slides.length === 0`, no matter how many slides are actually present. I assume this is because the original `countSlides` method is a stale closure.

Now, what I don't fully understand, is that if I adjust this line:

```js
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => sliderRef.current);
```

to this:

```js
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => () => {
    countSlides: () => sliderRef.current.countSlides()
  });
```

the stale closure is fixed and everything works as intended. But this is duplicative code and I'm just not sure what is even different between the two cases. I do not want to repeat myself redefining many methods within the `useImperativeHandle` hook, but much more importantly, I want to understand what the difference is between the two examples above.

Thank you!

**EDIT** Adding full example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ssr-slider-6ywf9

Comment: Can you add codes of where you use the Slider component? I'd like to see its usage

Comment: If possible, I'd like to see the full version of your components as I tried to use both approaches you used, and both worked for me. https://codesandbox.io/s/use-imperative-handle-7ij5k?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: OK so I just went through your sandbox and figured out why yours works but mine doesn't.  You are effectively creating the same pattern as what I have demonstrated as working, but in a different place. 

This line creates a closure:

`onClick={() => {countRef1.current.increase();}}`

Which fixes the problem. But.. my code was doing this:

`onClick={countRef1?.current?.increase}`.

Also, I updated my post with a full example to demonstrate. So, the original problem remains, it's just ... moved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you commented that the problem arose only when writing like `onClick={ slider?.current?.prev }` instead of `onClick={() => { slider?.current?.prev() }}`

I have tried with my sandbox that I provided and got the same problem.

There're a few things here:

1. useRef doesn't trigger re-renders itself, which means even a ref is updated, no re-renders follow.
2. Without re-renders, what's bound to onClick will not be updated.

So, if we write like `onClick={slider?.current?.prev}`, what happens is:

1. The ref is initially undefined, which means onClick is undefined as well
2. No re-render is triggered, so, even if ref is updated with a new value, onClick stays undefined

But, if we write like `onClick={() => { slider?.current?.prev() }}`, what happens is:

1. slider?.current?.prev is initially undefined
2. onClick is bound to that anonymous function
3. slider?.current?.prev is updated, we have the expected function
4. When the button is clicked, the function is called, which triggers the latest value of `slider?.current?.prev`